# Spring Data Couchbase Repository not working with Spring Boot 3.x

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I have a Spring Boot Service which is connecting to Couchbase Db to perform basic Crud operations using spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase.

Spring Boot Version = 3.0.5
spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase version = 3.0.5

My Pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.librarymgt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org_libmgt_v1_svc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>org_libmgt_v1_svc</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My Couchbase Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"org.libmgt.repository"})
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Repository Looks like:

```
package org.libmgt.repository;

import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Collection;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Scope;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Scope("library_mgt")
@Collection("students")
public interface StudentsRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Students, String> {
}
```

On starting the application the service is giving following exception:

```
Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/couchbase/client/core/api/query/CoreQueryOptions
```

The same code was working fine with Spring Boot 2.7.7 before.
Stopped working after Spring Boot migration to 3.x.

Comment: spring-data-couchbase version is 5.0.4

Comment: Hi @Rahul, this appears to be a regression. I have this issue with Spring boot 3.2.3, I had to roll back to 3.2.2 and am waiting for a fix. They are currently talking about it in this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39740

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1910) this is related to the queryDSL being removed. The current solution is to add it back to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/couchbase/client/core/api/query/CoreQueryOptions

is not related to com.querydsl.

Comment: When I take your pom.xml and run " mvn dependency:tree", the section under spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase.jar is like this - and CoreQueryOptions is in com.couchbase.client:core-io:jar:2.4.4. So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase:jar:3.0.5:compile
   \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:jar:5.0.4:compile
      +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:6.0.7:compile
      +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.0.7:compile
      +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.0.4:compile
      +- com.couchbase.client:java-client:jar:3.4.4:compile
      |  \- com.couchbase.client:core-io:jar:2.4.4:compile
...

Comment: % jar -tvf core-io-2.4.4.jar | grep CoreQueryOptions
  1940 Wed Mar 08 13:23:58 PST 2023 com/couchbase/client/core/api/query/CoreQueryOptions.class

Comment: btw - the lates version of spring-boot is 3.2.3.  You may wish to generate a new pom.xml using Spring Initialzr.